# File.exists doesn't find the file in /usr/sbin folder

Tags: java, linux

I have a very strange problem, I have a code that check if the gluster cli tool is installed, on a Manjaro distribution it works.

```
List<String> GLUSTER_EXE_PATHS = List.of("/usr/bin/gluster", "/usr/sbin/gluster");
GLUSTER_EXE_PATHS.stream().map(Paths::get).map(Path::toFile).anyMatch(File::exists)
```

But the problem is that this code will return false on my Gentoo :

> ls -ailh /usr/sbin/gluster
>
> 17555959 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 454K  1 avril 16:02 /usr/sbin/gluster

I tried to find another way to find if this file exists like using this method :

```
static boolean exists(File link) {
        File[] kids = link.getParentFile().listFiles();
        return kids != null && Arrays.asList(kids).contains(link);
    }
```

But it doesn't find this file, and sure enough, if I print the content of the kids array :

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(kids));
```

I can't find it inside, for unknown reason, this file is not a symlink, and I don't understand why java can't find it, especially as it works for Centos 7, Manjaro, but not Gentoo, there must be something special for this file, but I can't find what.

> [/usr/sbin/2to3, /usr/sbin/2to3-3.9, /usr/sbin/[, /usr/sbin/accessdb, /usr/sbin/aclocal, /usr/sbin/aclocal-1.16, /usr/sbin/addftinfo, /usr/sbin/addgnupghome, /usr/sbin/addpart, /usr/sbin/addr2line, /usr/sbin/affixcompress, /usr/sbin/afmtodit, /usr/sbin/agetty, /usr/sbin/analyseplugin, /usr/sbin/analyze, /usr/sbin/aomdec, /usr/sbin/aomenc, /usr/sbin/applygnupgdefaults, /usr/sbin/applyplugin, /usr/sbin/appstream-builder, /usr/sbin/appstream-compose, /usr/sbin/appstream-util, /usr/sbin/apropos, /usr/sbin/ar, /usr/sbin/arch, /usr/sbin/as, /usr/sbin/aserver, /usr/sbin/asn1Coding, /usr/sbin/asn1Decoding, /usr/sbin/asn1Parser, /usr/sbin/aspell, /usr/sbin/aspell-import, /usr/sbin/attr, /usr/sbin/autoconf, /usr/sbin/autoconf2.69, /usr/sbin/autoheader, /usr/sbin/autoheader2.69, /usr/sbin/autom4te, /usr/sbin/autom4te2.69, /usr/sbin/automake, /usr/sbin/automake-1.16, /usr/sbin/autopoint, /usr/sbin/autoreconf, /usr/sbin/autoreconf2.69, /usr/sbin/autoscan, /usr/sbin/autoscan2.69, /usr/sbin/autoupdate, /usr/sbin/autoupdate2.69, /usr/sbin/avcstat, /usr/sbin/awk, /usr/sbin/b2sum, /usr/sbin/base32, /usr/sbin/base64, /usr/sbin/basename, /usr/sbin/basenc, /usr/sbin/bash, /usr/sbin/bashbug, /usr/sbin/bc, /usr/sbin/bison, /usr/sbin/blkdiscard, /usr/sbin/blkid, /usr/sbin/blkzone, /usr/sbin/blockdev, /usr/sbin/brotli, /usr/sbin/bsdcat, /usr/sbin/bsdcpio, /usr/sbin/bsdtar, /usr/sbin/bundle, /usr/sbin/bundler, /usr/sbin/bunzip2, /usr/sbin/bzcat, /usr/sbin/bzcmp, /usr/sbin/bzdiff, /usr/sbin/bzegrep, /usr/sbin/bzfgrep, /usr/sbin/bzfless, /usr/sbin/bzgrep, /usr/sbin/bzip2, /usr/sbin/bzip2recover, /usr/sbin/bzmore, /usr/sbin/c++, /usr/sbin/c++filt, /usr/sbin/c_rehash, /usr/sbin/ca-legacy, /usr/sbin/cairo-sphinx, /usr/sbin/cairo-trace, /usr/sbin/cal, /usr/sbin/callgrind_annotate, /usr/sbin/callgrind_control, /usr/sbin/capsh, /usr/sbin/captoinfo, /usr/sbin/cat, /usr/sbin/catchsegv, /usr/sbin/catman, /usr/sbin/cc, /usr/sbin/ccache, /usr/sbin/ccmake, /usr/sbin/cec-compliance, /usr/sbin/cec-ctl, /usr/sbin/cec-follower, /usr/sbin/certtool, /usr/sbin/certutil, /usr/sbin/cfdisk, /usr/sbin/cg_annotate, /usr/sbin/cg_diff, /usr/sbin/cg_merge, /usr/sbin/chacl, /usr/sbin/chcon, /usr/sbin/chcpu, /usr/sbin/chem, /usr/sbin/chgrp, /usr/sbin/chkcon, /usr/sbin/chmem, /usr/sbin/chmod, /usr/sbin/chmorph, /usr/sbin/choom, /usr/sbin/chown, /usr/sbin/chroot, /usr/sbin/chrt, /usr/sbin/cjpeg, /usr/sbin/cksum, /usr/sbin/clear, /usr/sbin/cmake, /usr/sbin/cmp, /usr/sbin/cmsutil, /usr/sbin/col, /usr/sbin/colcrt, /usr/sbin/colrm, /usr/sbin/column, /usr/sbin/comm, /usr/sbin/compute_av, /usr/sbin/compute_create, /usr/sbin/compute_member, /usr/sbin/compute_relabel, /usr/sbin/corelist, /usr/sbin/cp, /usr/sbin/cpack, /usr/sbin/cpan, /usr/sbin/cpio, /usr/sbin/cpp, /usr/sbin/cracklib-check, /usr/sbin/cracklib-format, /usr/sbin/cracklib-packer, /usr/sbin/cracklib-unpacker, /usr/sbin/create-cracklib-dict, /usr/sbin/createPYMB, /usr/sbin/crlutil, /usr/sbin/csplit, /usr/sbin/ctest, /usr/sbin/ctrlaltdel, /usr/sbin/cups-config, /usr/sbin/curl, /usr/sbin/curl-config, /usr/sbin/cut, /usr/sbin/cwebp, /usr/sbin/cx18-ctl, /usr/sbin/cxpm, /usr/sbin/cygdb, /usr/sbin/cython, /usr/sbin/cythonize, /usr/sbin/date, /usr/sbin/dav1d, /usr/sbin/dbus-send, /usr/sbin/dc, /usr/sbin/dd, /usr/sbin/debugedit, /usr/sbin/debuginfod, /usr/sbin/debuginfod-find, /usr/sbin/decode_tm6000, /usr/sbin/delpart, /usr/sbin/derb, /usr/sbin/desktop-file-edit, /usr/sbin/desktop-file-install, /usr/sbin/desktop-file-validate, /usr/sbin/df, /usr/sbin/diff, /usr/sbin/diff3, /usr/sbin/dir, /usr/sbin/dircolors, /usr/sbin/dirmngr, /usr/sbin/dirmngr-client, /usr/sbin/dirname, /usr/sbin/djpeg, /usr/sbin/dmesg, /usr/sbin/doxygen, /usr/sbin/du, /usr/sbin/dumpsexp, /usr/sbin/dvb-fe-tool, /usr/sbin/dvb-format-convert, /usr/sbin/dvbv5-daemon, /usr/sbin/dvbv5-scan, /usr/sbin/dvbv5-zap, /usr/sbin/dwebp, /usr/sbin/dwp, /usr/sbin/dwz, /usr/sbin/echo, /usr/sbin/ed, /usr/sbin/egrep, /usr/sbin/eject, /usr/sbin/elfedit, /usr/sbin/enc2xs, /usr/sbin/encguess, /usr/sbin/env, /usr/sbin/envsubst, /usr/sbin/eqn, /usr/sbin/eqn2graph, /usr/sbin/erb, /usr/sbin/escapesrc, /usr/sbin/eu-addr2line, /usr/sbin/eu-ar, /usr/sbin/eu-elfclassify, /usr/sbin/eu-elfcmp, /usr/sbin/eu-elfcompress, /usr/sbin/eu-elflint, /usr/sbin/eu-findtextrel, /usr/sbin/eu-make-debug-archive, /usr/sbin/eu-nm, /usr/sbin/eu-objdump, /usr/sbin/eu-ranlib, /usr/sbin/eu-readelf, /usr/sbin/eu-size, /usr/sbin/eu-stack, /usr/sbin/eu-strings, /usr/sbin/eu-strip, /usr/sbin/eu-unstrip, /usr/sbin/expand, /usr/sbin/expr, /usr/sbin/factor, /usr/sbin/fallocate, /usr/sbin/false, /usr/sbin/fax2ps, /usr/sbin/fax2tiff, /usr/sbin/fc-cache, /usr/sbin/fc-cat, /usr/sbin/fc-conflist, /usr/sbin/fc-list, /usr/sbin/fc-match, /usr/sbin/fc-pattern, /usr/sbin/fc-query, /usr/sbin/fc-scan, /usr/sbin/fc-validate, /usr/sbin/fcitx, /usr/sbin/fcitx-autostart, /usr/sbin/fcitx-configtool, /usr/sbin/fcitx-dbus-watcher, /usr/sbin/fcitx-diagnose, /usr/sbin/fcitx-remote, /usr/sbin/fcitx4-config, /usr/sbin/fdisk, /usr/sbin/ffmpeg, /usr/sbin/ffplay, /usr/sbin/ffprobe, /usr/sbin/fftw-wisdom, /usr/sbin/fftw-wisdom-to-conf, /usr/sbin/fgrep, /usr/sbin/file, /usr/sbin/fincore, /usr/sbin/find, /usr/sbin/find-debuginfo, /usr/sbin/findfs, /usr/sbin/findmnt, /usr/sbin/flac, /usr/sbin/flatpak-spawn, /usr/sbin/flex, /usr/sbin/flex++, /usr/sbin/flock, /usr/sbin/fmt, /usr/sbin/fold, /usr/sbin/free, /usr/sbin/freedesktop-sdk-stripper, /usr/sbin/fribidi, /usr/sbin/fsck, /usr/sbin/fsck.cramfs, /usr/sbin/fsck.minix, /usr/sbin/fsfreeze, /usr/sbin/fstrim, /usr/sbin/funzip, /usr/sbin/g++, /usr/sbin/g-ir-annotation-tool, /usr/sbin/g-ir-compiler, /usr/sbin/g-ir-doc-tool, /usr/sbin/g-ir-generate, /usr/sbin/g-ir-inspect, /usr/sbin/g-ir-scanner, /usr/sbin/gapplication, /usr/sbin/gawk, /usr/sbin/gcab, /usr/sbin/gcc, /usr/sbin/gcc-ar, /usr/sbin/gcc-nm, /usr/sbin/gcc-ranlib, /usr/sbin/gcore, /usr/sbin/gcov, /usr/sbin/gcov-dump, /usr/sbin/gcov-tool, /usr/sbin/gdb, /usr/sbin/gdb-add-index, /usr/sbin/gdbm_dump, /usr/sbin/gdbm_load, /usr/sbin/gdbmtool, /usr/sbin/gdbserver, /usr/sbin/gdbus, /usr/sbin/gdbus-codegen, /usr/sbin/gdialog, /usr/sbin/gdiffmk, /usr/sbin/gdk-pixbuf-csource, /usr/sbin/gdk-pixbuf-pixdata, /usr/sbin/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders, /usr/sbin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer, /usr/sbin/gem, /usr/sbin/genbrk, /usr/sbin/gencat, /usr/sbin/genccode, /usr/sbin/gencfu, /usr/sbin/gencmn, /usr/sbin/gencnval, /usr/sbin/gendict, /usr/sbin/gennorm2, /usr/sbin/genrb, /usr/sbin/gensprep, /usr/sbin/getcap, /usr/sbin/getconf, /usr/sbin/getconlist, /usr/sbin/getdefaultcon, /usr/sbin/getenforce, /usr/sbin/getent, /usr/sbin/getfacl, /usr/sbin/getfattr, /usr/sbin/getfilecon, /usr/sbin/getopt, /usr/sbin/getpcaps, /usr/sbin/getpidcon, /usr/sbin/getsebool, /usr/sbin/getseuser, /usr/sbin/gettext, /usr/sbin/gettext.sh, /usr/sbin/gettextize, /usr/sbin/gfortran, /usr/sbin/gif2rgb, /usr/sbin/gif2webp, /usr/sbin/gifbuild, /usr/sbin/gifclrmp, /usr/sbin/giffix, /usr/sbin/giftext, /usr/sbin/giftool, /usr/sbin/gio, /usr/sbin/gio-querymodules, /usr/sbin/git, /usr/sbin/git-cvsserver, /usr/sbin/git-receive-pack, /usr/sbin/git-shell, /usr/sbin/git-upload-archive, /usr/sbin/git-upload-pack, /usr/sbin/gitk, /usr/sbin/glib-compile-resources, /usr/sbin/glib-compile-schemas, /usr/sbin/glib-genmarshal, /usr/sbin/glib-gettextize, /usr/sbin/glib-mkenums, /usr/sbin/glilypond, /usr/sbin/glslangValidator, /usr/sbin/gnutls-cli, /usr/sbin/gnutls-cli-debug, /usr/sbin/gnutls-serv, /usr/sbin/gobject-query, /usr/sbin/gperf, /usr/sbin/gperl, /usr/sbin/gpg, /usr/sbin/gpg-agent, /usr/sbin/gpg-connect-agent, /usr/sbin/gpg-error, /usr/sbin/gpg-error-config, /usr/sbin/gpg-wks-server, /usr/sbin/gpgconf, /usr/sbin/gpgme-config, /usr/sbin/gpgme-json, /usr/sbin/gpgme-tool, /usr/sbin/gpgparsemail, /usr/sbin/gpgrt-config, /usr/sbin/gpgscm, /usr/sbin/gpgsm, /usr/sbin/gpgsplit, /usr/sbin/gpgtar, /usr/sbin/gpgv, /usr/sbin/gpinyin, /usr/sbin/gprof, /usr/sbin/gr2fonttest, /usr/sbin/grap2graph, /usr/sbin/grep, /usr/sbin/gresource, /usr/sbin/grn, /usr/sbin/grodvi, /usr/sbin/groff, /usr/sbin/groffer, /usr/sbin/grog, /usr/sbin/grolbp, /usr/sbin/grolj4, /usr/sbin/gropdf, /usr/sbin/grops, /usr/sbin/grotty, /usr/sbin/gsettings, /usr/sbin/gst-device-monitor-1.0, /usr/sbin/gst-discoverer-1.0, /usr/sbin/gst-inspect-1.0, /usr/sbin/gst-launch-1.0, /usr/sbin/gst-play-1.0, /usr/sbin/gst-stats-1.0, /usr/sbin/gst-tester-1.0, /usr/sbin/gst-transcoder-1.0, /usr/sbin/gst-typefind-1.0, /usr/sbin/gtester, /usr/sbin/gtester-report, /usr/sbin/gtk-builder-tool, /usr/sbin/gtk-encode-symbolic-svg, /usr/sbin/gtk-launch, /usr/sbin/gtk-query-immodules-3.0, /usr/sbin/gtk-query-settings, /usr/sbin/gtk-update-icon-cache, /usr/sbin/gtk3-demo, /usr/sbin/gtk3-demo-application, /usr/sbin/gtk3-icon-browser, /usr/sbin/gtk3-widget-factory, /usr/sbin/gtkdoc-check, /usr/sbin/gtkdoc-depscan, /usr/sbin/gtkdoc-fixxref, /usr/sbin/gtkdoc-mkdb, /usr/sbin/gtkdoc-mkhtml, /usr/sbin/gtkdoc-mkhtml2, /usr/sbin/gtkdoc-mkman, /usr/sbin/gtkdoc-mkpdf, /usr/sbin/gtkdoc-rebase, /usr/sbin/gtkdoc-scan, /usr/sbin/gtkdoc-scangobj, /usr/sbin/gtkdocize, /usr/sbin/gunzip, /usr/sbin/gzexe, /usr/sbin/gzip, /usr/sbin/h2ph, /usr/sbin/h2xs, /usr/sbin/hardlink, /usr/sbin/hb-ot-shape-closure, /usr/sbin/hb-shape, /usr/sbin/hb-subset, /usr/sbin/head, /usr/sbin/help2man, /usr/sbin/hexdump, /usr/sbin/hmac256, /usr/sbin/hostid, /usr/sbin/hostname, /usr/sbin/hpftodit, /usr/sbin/hunspell, /usr/sbin/hunzip, /usr/sbin/hw-support, /usr/sbin/hwclock, /usr/sbin/hzip, /usr/sbin/i386, /usr/sbin/iconv, /usr/sbin/iconvconfig, /usr/sbin/icu-config, /usr/sbin/icuinfo, /usr/sbin/icupkg, /usr/sbin/id, /usr/sbin/idn2, /usr/sbin/ifnames, /usr/sbin/ifnames2.69, /usr/sbin/img2webp, /usr/sbin/indxbib, /usr/sbin/info, /usr/sbin/infocmp, /usr/sbin/infotocap, /usr/sbin/install, /usr/sbin/install-info, /usr/sbin/instmodsh, /usr/sbin/ionice, /usr/sbin/ipcmk, /usr/sbin/ipcrm, /usr/sbin/ipcs, /usr/sbin/ir-ctl, /usr/sbin/ir-keytable, /usr/sbin/irb, /usr/sbin/irqtop, /usr/sbin/isosize, /usr/sbin/ispellaff2myspell, /usr/sbin/itstool, /usr/sbin/ivtv-ctl, /usr/sbin/join, /usr/sbin/jpegtran, /usr/sbin/jpgicc, /usr/sbin/jq, /usr/sbin/json-glib-format, /usr/sbin/json-glib-validate, /usr/sbin/json_pp, /usr/sbin/kbxutil, /usr/sbin/kill, /usr/sbin/ksba-config, /usr/sbin/lame, /usr/sbin/last, /usr/sbin/lastb, /usr/sbin/ld, /usr/sbin/ld.bfd, /usr/sbin/ld.gold, /usr/sbin/ldattach, /usr/sbin/ldconfig, /usr/sbin/ldd, /usr/sbin/less, /usr/sbin/lessecho, /usr/sbin/lesskey, /usr/sbin/lexgrog, /usr/sbin/libassuan-config, /usr/sbin/libgcrypt-config, /usr/sbin/libnetcfg, /usr/sbin/libpng-config, /usr/sbin/libpng16-config, /usr/sbin/libtool, /usr/sbin/libtoolize, /usr/sbin/link, /usr/sbin/linkicc, /usr/sbin/linux32, /usr/sbin/linux64, /usr/sbin/listplugins, /usr/sbin/lkbib, /usr/sbin/ln, /usr/sbin/locale, /usr/sbin/localedef, /usr/sbin/locate, /usr/sbin/logger, /usr/sbin/logname, /usr/sbin/look, /usr/sbin/lookbib, /usr/sbin/losetup, /usr/sbin/ls, /usr/sbin/lsblk, /usr/sbin/lscpu, /usr/sbin/lsipc, /usr/sbin/lsirq, /usr/sbin/lslocks, /usr/sbin/lslogins, /usr/sbin/lsmem, /usr/sbin/lsns, /usr/sbin/lspci, /usr/sbin/lto-dump, /usr/sbin/lz4, /usr/sbin/lz4c, /usr/sbin/lz4cat, /usr/sbin/lzcat, /usr/sbin/lzcmp, /usr/sbin/lzdiff, /usr/sbin/lzegrep, /usr/sbin/lzfgrep, /usr/sbin/lzgrep, /usr/sbin/lzip, /usr/sbin/lzless, /usr/sbin/lzma, /usr/sbin/lzmadec, /usr/sbin/lzmainfo, /usr/sbin/lzmore, /usr/sbin/m4, /usr/sbin/make, /usr/sbin/makealias, /usr/sbin/makeconv, /usr/sbin/makedb, /usr/sbin/makeinfo, /usr/sbin/mako-render, /usr/sbin/man, /usr/sbin/man-recode, /usr/sbin/mandb, /usr/sbin/manpath, /usr/sbin/markdown_py, /usr/sbin/matchpathcon, /usr/sbin/mb2org, /usr/sbin/mb2txt, /usr/sbin/mcookie, /usr/sbin/md5sum, /usr/sbin/media-ctl, /usr/sbin/mesg, /usr/sbin/meson, /usr/sbin/metaflac, /usr/sbin/mkdir, /usr/sbin/mkfifo, /usr/sbin/mkfs, /usr/sbin/mkfs.bfs, /usr/sbin/mkfs.cramfs, /usr/sbin/mkfs.minix, /usr/sbin/mknod, /usr/sbin/mkswap, /usr/sbin/mktemp, /usr/sbin/mmroff, /usr/sbin/modutil, /usr/sbin/more, /usr/sbin/mount, /usr/sbin/mountpoint, /usr/sbin/mpicalc, /usr/sbin/ms_print, /usr/sbin/msgattrib, /usr/sbin/msgcat, /usr/sbin/msgcmp, /usr/sbin/msgcomm, /usr/sbin/msgconv, /usr/sbin/msgen, /usr/sbin/msgexec, /usr/sbin/msgfilter, /usr/sbin/msgfmt, /usr/sbin/msggrep, /usr/sbin/msginit, /usr/sbin/msgmerge, /usr/sbin/msgunfmt, /usr/sbin/msguniq, /usr/sbin/mtrace, /usr/sbin/munch, /usr/sbin/mv, /usr/sbin/namei, /usr/sbin/nano, /usr/sbin/nasm, /usr/sbin/ncurses6-config, /usr/sbin/ncursesw6-config, /usr/sbin/ndisasm, /usr/sbin/neqn, /usr/sbin/nettle-hash, /usr/sbin/nettle-lfib-stream, /usr/sbin/nettle-pbkdf2, /usr/sbin/ngettext, /usr/sbin/nice, /usr/sbin/ninja, /usr/sbin/nl, /usr/sbin/nm, /usr/sbin/nohup, /usr/sbin/nproc, /usr/sbin/npth-config, /usr/sbin/nroff, /usr/sbin/nscd, /usr/sbin/nsenter, /usr/sbin/nspr-config, /usr/sbin/nss, /usr/sbin/nss-config, /usr/sbin/numfmt, /usr/sbin/objcopy, /usr/sbin/objdump, /usr/sbin/ocsptool, /usr/sbin/od, /usr/sbin/onig-config, /usr/sbin/openal-info, /usr/sbin/openssl, /usr/sbin/opj_compress, /usr/sbin/opj_decompress, /usr/sbin/opj_dump, /usr/sbin/orcc, /usr/sbin/p11-kit, /usr/sbin/p11tool, /usr/sbin/pa-info, /usr/sbin/pacat, /usr/sbin/pacmd, /usr/sbin/pactl, /usr/sbin/padsp, /usr/sbin/pal2rgb, /usr/sbin/pamon, /usr/sbin/pango-list, /usr/sbin/pango-segmentation, /usr/sbin/pango-view, /usr/sbin/paplay, /usr/sbin/parec, /usr/sbin/parecord, /usr/sbin/partx, /usr/sbin/paste, /usr/sbin/patch, /usr/sbin/pathchk, /usr/sbin/pax11publish, /usr/sbin/pcprofiledump, /usr/sbin/pcre-config, /usr/sbin/pcre2-config, /usr/sbin/pcre2grep, /usr/sbin/pcre2test, /usr/sbin/pcregrep, /usr/sbin/pcretest, /usr/sbin/pdfmom, /usr/sbin/pdfroff, /usr/sbin/pdftexi2dvi, /usr/sbin/perf, /usr/sbin/perl, /usr/sbin/perl5.34.0, /usr/sbin/perlbug, /usr/sbin/perldoc, /usr/sbin/perlivp, /usr/sbin/perlthanks, /usr/sbin/pfbtops, /usr/sbin/pgrep, /usr/sbin/pic, /usr/sbin/pic2graph, /usr/sbin/piconv, /usr/sbin/pidof, /usr/sbin/pinky, /usr/sbin/pip3, /usr/sbin/pip3.9, /usr/sbin/pivot_root, /usr/sbin/pk12util, /usr/sbin/pkcs1-conv, /usr/sbin/pkg-config, /usr/sbin/pkgconf, /usr/sbin/pkgdata, /usr/sbin/pkill, /usr/sbin/pl2pm, /usr/sbin/playout, /usr/sbin/pldd, /usr/sbin/pluginviewer, /usr/sbin/pmap, /usr/sbin/png-fix-itxt, /usr/sbin/pngfix, /usr/sbin/pod2html, /usr/sbin/pod2man, /usr/sbin/pod2texi, /usr/sbin/pod2text, /usr/sbin/pod2usage, /usr/sbin/podchecker, /usr/sbin/policyvers, /usr/sbin/post-grohtml, /usr/sbin/ppm2tiff, /usr/sbin/pr, /usr/sbin/pre-grohtml, /usr/sbin/precat, /usr/sbin/preconv, /usr/sbin/preunzip, /usr/sbin/prezip, /usr/sbin/prezip-bin, /usr/sbin/printenv, /usr/sbin/printf, /usr/sbin/prlimit, /usr/sbin/prove, /usr/sbin/proxy, /usr/sbin/ps, /usr/sbin/psicc, /usr/sbin/psktool, /usr/sbin/psl, /usr/sbin/pspell-config, /usr/sbin/ptar, /usr/sbin/ptardiff, /usr/sbin/ptargrep, /usr/sbin/ptx, /usr/sbin/pw-cat, /usr/sbin/pw-cli, /usr/sbin/pw-dot, /usr/sbin/pw-dump, /usr/sbin/pw-jack, /usr/sbin/pw-link, /usr/sbin/pw-loopback, /usr/sbin/pw-metadata, /usr/sbin/pw-mididump, /usr/sbin/pw-midiplay, /usr/sbin/pw-midirecord, /usr/sbin/pw-mon, /usr/sbin/pw-play, /usr/sbin/pw-profiler, /usr/sbin/pw-record, /usr/sbin/pw-reserve, /usr/sbin/pw-top, /usr/sbin/pwait, /usr/sbin/pwd, /usr/sbin/pwdecrypt, /usr/sbin/pwdx, /usr/sbin/pydoc3, /usr/sbin/pydoc3.9, /usr/sbin/pygmentize, /usr/sbin/python, /usr/sbin/python3, /usr/sbin/python3-config, /usr/sbin/python3.9, /usr/sbin/python3.9-config, /usr/sbin/racc, /usr/sbin/rake, /usr/sbin/ranlib, /usr/sbin/raw2tiff, /usr/sbin/rbs, /usr/sbin/rdjpgcom, /usr/sbin/rdoc, /usr/sbin/rds-ctl, /usr/sbin/readPYBase, /usr/sbin/readPYMB, /usr/sbin/readelf, /usr/sbin/readlink, /usr/sbin/readprofile, /usr/sbin/realpath, /usr/sbin/recode-sr-latin, /usr/sbin/red, /usr/sbin/refer, /usr/sbin/rename, /usr/sbin/renice, /usr/sbin/reset, /usr/sbin/resizepart, /usr/sbin/rev, /usr/sbin/rfkill, /usr/sbin/ri, /usr/sbin/rm, /usr/sbin/rmdir, /usr/sbin/rnano, /usr/sbin/roff2dvi, /usr/sbin/roff2html, /usr/sbin/roff2pdf, /usr/sbin/roff2ps, /usr/sbin/roff2text, /usr/sbin/roff2x, /usr/sbin/rsvg-convert, /usr/sbin/rtcwake, /usr/sbin/ruby, /usr/sbin/run-with-aspell, /usr/sbin/runcon, /usr/sbin/saslauthd, /usr/sbin/sasldblistusers2, /usr/sbin/saslpasswd2, /usr/sbin/scel2org, /usr/sbin/scmp_sys_resolver, /usr/sbin/scp, /usr/sbin/script, /usr/sbin/scriptlive, /usr/sbin/scriptreplay, /usr/sbin/sdiff, /usr/sbin/sdl2-config, /usr/sbin/sed, /usr/sbin/sefcontext_compile, /usr/sbin/selabel_digest, /usr/sbin/selabel_get_digests_all_partial_matches, /usr/sbin/selabel_lookup, /usr/sbin/selabel_lookup_best_match, /usr/sbin/selabel_partial_match, /usr/sbin/selinux_check_access, /usr/sbin/selinux_check_securetty_context, /usr/sbin/selinuxenabled, /usr/sbin/selinuxexeccon, /usr/sbin/sepdebugcrcfix, /usr/sbin/seq, /usr/sbin/setarch, /usr/sbin/setcap, /usr/sbin/setenforce, /usr/sbin/setfacl, /usr/sbin/setfattr, /usr/sbin/setfilecon, /usr/sbin/setpci, /usr/sbin/setsid, /usr/sbin/setterm, /usr/sbin/sexp-conv, /usr/sbin/sfdisk, /usr/sbin/sftp, /usr/sbin/sh, /usr/sbin/sha1sum, /usr/sbin/sha224sum, /usr/sbin/sha256sum, /usr/sbin/sha384sum, /usr/sbin/sha512sum, /usr/sbin/shasum, /usr/sbin/shlibsign, /usr/sbin/shred, /usr/sbin/shuf, /usr/sbin/signtool, /usr/sbin/signver, /usr/sbin/size, /usr/sbin/slabtop, /usr/sbin/sleep, /usr/sbin/sln, /usr/sbin/slsh, /usr/sbin/sndfile-cmp, /usr/sbin/sndfile-concat, /usr/sbin/sndfile-convert, /usr/sbin/sndfile-deinterleave, /usr/sbin/sndfile-info, /usr/sbin/sndfile-interleave, /usr/sbin/sndfile-metadata-get, /usr/sbin/sndfile-metadata-set, /usr/sbin/sndfile-play, /usr/sbin/sndfile-resample, /usr/sbin/sndfile-salvage, /usr/sbin/soelim, /usr/sbin/sort, /usr/sbin/sotruss, /usr/sbin/spa-acp-tool, /usr/sbin/spa-inspect, /usr/sbin/spa-json-dump, /usr/sbin/spa-monitor, /usr/sbin/spa-resample, /usr/sbin/speexdec, /usr/sbin/speexenc, /usr/sbin/spirv-as, /usr/sbin/spirv-cfg, /usr/sbin/spirv-dis, /usr/sbin/spirv-lesspipe.sh, /usr/sbin/spirv-link, /usr/sbin/spirv-lint, /usr/sbin/spirv-opt, /usr/sbin/spirv-reduce, /usr/sbin/spirv-remap, /usr/sbin/spirv-val, /usr/sbin/splain, /usr/sbin/split, /usr/sbin/sprof, /usr/sbin/sqlite3, /usr/sbin/srptool, /usr/sbin/ssh, /usr/sbin/ssh-add, /usr/sbin/ssh-agent, /usr/sbin/ssh-keygen, /usr/sbin/ssh-keyscan, /usr/sbin/ssltap, /usr/sbin/stat, /usr/sbin/stdbuf, /usr/sbin/strace, /usr/sbin/strace-log-merge, /usr/sbin/streamzip, /usr/sbin/strings, /usr/sbin/strip, /usr/sbin/stty, /usr/sbin/stunbdc, /usr/sbin/stund, /usr/sbin/substrings.pl, /usr/sbin/sulogin, /usr/sbin/sum, /usr/sbin/swaplabel, /usr/sbin/swapoff, /usr/sbin/swapon, /usr/sbin/switch_root, /usr/sbin/symkeyutil, /usr/sbin/sync, /usr/sbin/sysctl, /usr/sbin/tabs, /usr/sbin/tac, /usr/sbin/tail, /usr/sbin/tar, /usr/sbin/taskset, /usr/sbin/tbl, /usr/sbin/tee, /usr/sbin/test, /usr/sbin/testsaslauthd, /usr/sbin/texi2any, /usr/sbin/texi2dvi, /usr/sbin/texi2pdf, /usr/sbin/texindex, /usr/sbin/tfmtodit, /usr/sbin/th_gen_idx.pl, /usr/sbin/tic, /usr/sbin/tiff2bw, /usr/sbin/tiff2pdf, /usr/sbin/tiff2ps, /usr/sbin/tiff2rgba, /usr/sbin/tiffcmp, /usr/sbin/tiffcp, /usr/sbin/tiffcrop, /usr/sbin/tiffdither, /usr/sbin/tiffdump, /usr/sbin/tiffinfo, /usr/sbin/tiffmedian, /usr/sbin/tiffset, /usr/sbin/tiffsplit, /usr/sbin/tificc, /usr/sbin/timeout, /usr/sbin/tjbench, /usr/sbin/tload, /usr/sbin/toe, /usr/sbin/togglesebool, /usr/sbin/top, /usr/sbin/touch, /usr/sbin/tput, /usr/sbin/tr, /usr/sbin/trace, /usr/sbin/transicc, /usr/sbin/trietool, /usr/sbin/trietool-0.2, /usr/sbin/troff, /usr/sbin/true, /usr/sbin/truncate, /usr/sbin/trust, /usr/sbin/tset, /usr/sbin/tsort, /usr/sbin/tty, /usr/sbin/txt2mb, /usr/sbin/typeprof, /usr/sbin/tzselect, /usr/sbin/uclampset, /usr/sbin/uconv, /usr/sbin/ul, /usr/sbin/umount, /usr/sbin/uname, /usr/sbin/uname26, /usr/sbin/uncompress, /usr/sbin/unexpand, /usr/sbin/uniq, /usr/sbin/unlink, /usr/sbin/unlz4, /usr/sbin/unlzma, /usr/sbin/unmunch, /usr/sbin/unshare, /usr/sbin/unxz, /usr/sbin/unzip, /usr/sbin/unzipsfx, /usr/sbin/unzstd, /usr/sbin/update-ca-trust, /usr/sbin/update-desktop-database, /usr/sbin/update-mime-database, /usr/sbin/update-pciids, /usr/sbin/updatedb, /usr/sbin/uptime, /usr/sbin/users, /usr/sbin/utmpdump, /usr/sbin/uuidd, /usr/sbin/uuidgen, /usr/sbin/uuidparse, /usr/sbin/v4l2-compliance, /usr/sbin/v4l2-ctl, /usr/sbin/v4l2-dbg, /usr/sbin/v4l2-sysfs-path, /usr/sbin/valgrind, /usr/sbin/valgrind-di-server, /usr/sbin/valgrind-listener, /usr/sbin/validatetrans, /usr/sbin/vdir, /usr/sbin/vgdb, /usr/sbin/vmstat, /usr/sbin/vpxdec, /usr/sbin/vpxenc, /usr/sbin/w, /usr/sbin/watch, /usr/sbin/watchgnupg, /usr/sbin/wavpack, /usr/sbin/wayland-scanner, /usr/sbin/wc, /usr/sbin/wdctl, /usr/sbin/webpinfo, /usr/sbin/webpmux, /usr/sbin/wget, /usr/sbin/whatis, /usr/sbin/wheel, /usr/sbin/whereis, /usr/sbin/which, /usr/sbin/who, /usr/sbin/whoami, /usr/sbin/wipefs, /usr/sbin/word-list-compress, /usr/sbin/wordforms, /usr/sbin/wordlist2hunspell, /usr/sbin/wrjpgcom, /usr/sbin/wvgain, /usr/sbin/wvtag, /usr/sbin/wvunpack, /usr/sbin/x86_64, /usr/sbin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-c++, /usr/sbin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++, /usr/sbin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc, /usr/sbin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-11.3.0, /usr/sbin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-ar, /usr/sbin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-nm, /usr/sbin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib, /usr/sbin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gfortran, /usr/sbin/xargs, /usr/sbin/xdg-email, /usr/sbin/xdg-open, /usr/sbin/xdg-user-dir, /usr/sbin/xdg-user-dirs-update, /usr/sbin/xgettext, /usr/sbin/xkbcli, /usr/sbin/xkbcomp, /usr/sbin/xml2-config, /usr/sbin/xmlcatalog, /usr/sbin/xmllint, /usr/sbin/xmlwf, /usr/sbin/xslt-config, /usr/sbin/xsltproc, /usr/sbin/xsubpp, /usr/sbin/xtrace, /usr/sbin/xz, /usr/sbin/xzcat, /usr/sbin/xzcmp, /usr/sbin/xzdec, /usr/sbin/xzdiff, /usr/sbin/xzegrep, /usr/sbin/xzfgrep, /usr/sbin/xzgrep, /usr/sbin/xzless, /usr/sbin/xzmore, /usr/sbin/yacc, /usr/sbin/yes, /usr/sbin/zcat, /usr/sbin/zcmp, /usr/sbin/zdiff, /usr/sbin/zdump, /usr/sbin/zegrep, /usr/sbin/zenity, /usr/sbin/zfgrep, /usr/sbin/zforce, /usr/sbin/zgrep, /usr/sbin/zic, /usr/sbin/zip, /usr/sbin/zipcloak, /usr/sbin/zipdetails, /usr/sbin/zipgrep, /usr/sbin/zipinfo, /usr/sbin/zipnote, /usr/sbin/zipsplit, /usr/sbin/zless, /usr/sbin/zmore, /usr/sbin/znew, /usr/sbin/zramctl, /usr/sbin/zstd, /usr/sbin/zstdcat, /usr/sbin/zstdgrep, /usr/sbin/zstdless, /usr/sbin/zstdmt]

Comment: Have you verified that neither `/usr/` nor `/usr/sbin/` are symlinks?

Comment: They both are not symlinks, but I thought about something, I am running this code in IntelliJ that I have installed via Flatpak, maybe flatpak is limiting what can be seen. I am checking that.

Comment: Ok, so in the flatpack environment, there are some blacklisted folder as explained here : https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html

Comment: You can answer your own question with this information. It will be helpful to future visitors

Comment: Yes, that was the plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, in my Gentoo machine, I am using Flatpak for installing and using my IDE (IntelliJ in this case).

As stated here https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html, the sandbox environment used to run flakpak packaged applications some folders are blacklisted as the flakpak environment is already providing his own folders, these are : /lib, /lib32, /lib64, /bin, /sbin, /usr, /boot, /root, /tmp, /etc, /app, /run, /proc, /sys, /dev, /var

In the flapak environment, the host folders are accessible in the /var/run/host/ folder.

My code must be updated like so :

```
List<String> GLUSTER_EXE_PATHS = List.of("/usr/bin/gluster", "/usr/sbin/gluster", "/var/run/host/usr/sbin/gluster");
GLUSTER_EXE_PATHS.stream().map(Paths::get).map(Path::toFile).anyMatch(File::exists)
```

And now it works, as the last path I have added is the host one from the flatpak environment.